# Estimate of the hypergeometric function $_3F_2$

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, estimation, hypergeometric-function

How to estimate the following function?
$$
_3F_2\begingroup
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}
% your pmatrix expression
\left[
\begin{array}{c@{}c}
 \begin{array}{c}
         -q, \frac{M}{2}, \frac{1}{2}+\frac{M}{2}\\ 
                       \frac{1}{2}, -q-\frac{N-M}{2}+1
                      \end{array} ;& 1
 \end{array}\right]\endgroup,
$$
where $q, M, N \in N$

Comment: how did you come across this function? have you tried anything? Since $q\in\Bbb N$, you know that the function is a polynomial--shouldn't this count as a closed form?

Comment: I have obtained it as a sum of the series, you are right. I met to write in the topic: estimation of the closed form function $_3F_2$